# My program runs well on gnu-gcc but not on gnu gcc for avr

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks, avr-gcc, winavr

I'm learning C. So I wrote this distance timer program. 
It runs well with gnu-gcc compiler.
But but with gnu-gcc for avr it does compile but when I run it I get only a cmd session that does nothing except disappearing once I press any button.
I want to know why.

I am using code blocks and here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define speedpersecond 5

int main()

{

char time  [5];

double distance;

printf("Please enter time in seconds");

gets(time);

distance = atoi(time) * speedpersecond;

printf("Distance is %g ", distance);

return 8585;

}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets`. And why are you returning `8585`? Try returning 0

Comment: Never thought that it would make any difference just return any number will do.

Comment: Mmh...where do you run the program you have compiled with gcc-avr? On your PC or on the microcontroller?

Comment: @AllanMayers What are you typing in as input?  Is the length greater than 4 characters?

Comment: I am learning c to use it with micro controllers so I wanted to get familiar with avr gcc from the start . I thought it would compile a console application on my laptop with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into the reason `gets` have been deprecated since the C99 standard, and removed completely in the C11 standard: Buffer overflows are way to easy.

If you give more than four characters as input then `gets` will write out of bounds of the array and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Instead use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read lines in a safe way.

---

And regarding that `return` from the `main` function. Many systems (including *all* POSIX systems, like macOS and Linux) uses eight bits for the return value. Also, anything but zero is considered to be a failure by shells and calling environments.

You should also know that the `atoi` function have no major error checking. It's impossible to know if the string you pass contains e.g. `"0"` or don't have any digits at all. In both cases it will return `0`. A safer function which will help you detect errors is the [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function.

Comment: Ok and that strtol function is it used the same way as atoi?

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: @AllanMayers Follow the link, it leads to a reference which have an example.